# WebSocket Server Colliding with Clients from Different Hosts

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am having one peculiar problem currently with WebSockets.
My setup is like below:

[image: Server Setup]

For some reason, in the above setup, `Server 2` is getting messages from `Client 1` and vice versa. Strange thing is that it's not everytime. It happens sometimes.

Router 1 and 2 are connected via Ethernet and are having single ISP.

I am running each Web Socket server in `127.0.0.1` and on **different Ports** (e.g Server 1 on `8081` and Server 2 on `8091`).

I am still not understanding how it's technically possible for this to happen when they don't have anything in common? Is it possible, if yes what is the reason behind this?

How do I disable this behaviour?

Here my client is `Electron JS` app and Server is written using NodeJS WebSocket.

How is it possible for different machine client to connect to different server running on different machine only having different router?

I added the following code in my server code to ignore messages coming from different machine's client but it's still not working

```
if (
      ws._socket.remoteAddress != "127.0.0.1" &&
      ws._socket.remoteAddress != "::1"
    ) {
      return;
}
```